# Trying to populate a drop down on select of a radio button

Tags: meteor

The default should be a checked radio button with text area box.As the second radio button is checked the text area box must be replaced with a drop down with values.My code is below

```
<div>
  <label><input type="radio" name="billingcustname" value="new" id="billingcustname_0" checked="checked">New </label>
        {{#if showNewCustomer}}
            {{> newcustomer}}
        {{else}}
            {{> existingcustomer}}
        {{/if}}
  <label><input type="radio" name="billingcustname" value="existing" id="billingcustname_1">Existing</label>
</div>
<template name="newcustomer">
  <input type="text" class="form-control newCust" placeholder="Customer Name">
</template>

<template name="existingcustomer">
<select id="dropdown" class="form-control existCust">
    <option value="0" disabled="">Please select</option>        
    <option value="1800FLOWERS BPO AUTOMATION" selected="">1800FLOWERS AUTOMATION</option>      
</select>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Session inside a helper to populate your `<select>`. The best thing is that they are reactive so you will get your "on the fly" effect.

```
<select id="dropdown">
  {{#each options}}
    <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>

Template.name.helpers({
 options: function() {
   return Session.get('options_from_radio');
 }
});

Template.name.events({
  'click #billingcustname_0': function() {
    var new_options = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'];
    Session.set('options_from_radio', new_options);
  }
});
```

Of course the code above can be improved with adding a Session Array by default, setting Objects (for values and text) inside the Array rather than a String such as `[{value="ch1", text="Choose me first"}, {...}, {...}]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

@Radu is on the right track.

1. Create an event handler for the radio button that sets a Session var
2. Add a template helper that gets the Session var

To have events on your radio buttons you need to wrap that html in a template as well (always good practice, you should have zero html outside of templates).

**html:**

```
<template name="selector">
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="billingcustname" value="new" id="billingcustname_0" checked="checked">New </label>
    {{#if showNewCustomer}}
      {{> newcustomer}}
    {{else}}
      {{> existingcustomer}}
    {{/if}}
    <label><input type="radio" name="billingcustname" value="existing" id="billingcustname_1">Existing</label>
  </div>
</template>
```

**js:**

```
Template.selector.events({
  'click #billingcustname_0': function() {
    Session.set('showNewCustomer',true);
  },
  'click #billingcustname_1': function() {
    Session.set('showNewCustomer',false);
  }
});

Template.selector.onRendered(function(){
    Session.set('showNewCustomer',true);
});

Template.selector.helpers({
  showNewCustomer: function(){
    return Session.get('showNewCustomer');
  }
});
```

Personally though that seems like a lot of code for something so simple. I'd be tempted to revert to jQuery and just toggle the visibility of the elements on the page as the radio buttons are clicked.